# how to group and show the counts of multiple fields in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection in MongoDB that is generated via a data import of a CSV file. The data in the collection is for some basic reports and all the fields have been flattened and doesn't really look like a typical document.
Here is an example of 2 documents

{

"schoolCode": "0001",

```
"name": "Special Centre",
"ecsTaught": "N",
"elementaryTaught": "Y",
"juniorHighTaught": "N",
"seniorHighTaught": "N",
"authorityCode": "9000",
"offerHomeEducation": "N",
"offerHomeEducationBlended": "N",
"offerSchoolOnline": "N",
"offerSchoolOutreach": "N",
"extractDate": "2015-05-11"
```

}

{

"schoolCode": "0002",

```
"name": "High point Centre",
"ecsTaught": "y",
"elementaryTaught": "Y",
"juniorHighTaught": "N",
"seniorHighTaught": "Y",
"authorityCode": "9000",
"offerHomeEducation": "N",
"offerHomeEducationBlended": "N",
"offerSchoolOnline": "N",
"offerSchoolOutreach": "N",
"extractDate": "2015-05-11"
```

}

I would like to query using mongoose to get a count report as follows

- Ecs Taught : 20
- Elementatary Taught: 47
- JuniorHigh Taught: 55
- SeniorHigh Taught: 43

The count should take into account, any field that has "Y" and projected as above.
I am actually new to mongoose and have checked the docs but did not find much info on how to aggregate over multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will most likely be better off just retrieving the records (in chunks if the collection is large) and doing the aggregation yourself. MongoDB retrieves each document entirely anyway. Since you're using a considerable part of each document for your queries, it will be best to do the aggregation yourself.

That said, if you still want Mongoose to do it, use the aggregator function like [this](https://gist.github.com/kdelemme/9659364). The bad way would be to call this for each query you need, grouping by the fieldname and "Y/N" value - for each field you want to query.

A better way would be using [Model.mapReduce](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce) to perform a reduce operation. This way you'll can do more kinds of queries on each document.